# Star Conflict shows black screen on Linux

Tags: steam, steam-play, star-conflict

I just downloaded Star Conflict through Steam on Linux, and when I entered the game instead of all beautiful space objects and ships it just shows a black screen. I don't know what happened, maybe I am making some silly mistake, but if anyone knows how to solve this issue please tell me.

Comment: This question is tagged with epic-games-launcher, but the question says you use steam. Can you please clarify and double-check this question for correctness? Also, more details about the issue might be helpful in debugging your problem.

Comment: @Kadima ,oh yes I just change the tags